# C program using malloc and strcat prints nonsense

Tags: c, malloc, strcat

so I'm working on this program, it gets two numbers as string from a file then prints them. i also need to add leading zeros if necessary and that made me write conditional if-else so that i can detect if any of numbers is bigger than the other so i can add leading zeros.

for zeros i use malloc and a dynamic array and also i use strcat to add zeros and actual number together. it works fine but when printing it, it prints zeros and number with nonsense between them. 
how do i fix this and remove that thing between them??
int the picture below 12345644 is first number and 129 is second number.

red is wanted but blue is nonsense and i want it removed.

[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE_MAX 25

int main()
{

FILE *fPTR;

    char num_first[SIZE_MAX]; // string input
    char num_second[SIZE_MAX];

    if ((fPTR = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL) // our file contains two line of integers. one at each
    {
        puts("File could not be opened.");
    }
    else
    {
        if (fgets(num_first, SIZE_MAX, fPTR) != NULL) // reads first line and saves to num_first
            puts(num_first); // prints first number
        if (fgets(num_second, SIZE_MAX, fPTR) != NULL) // reads second line and saves to num_second
            puts(num_second); // prints second number
        fclose(fPTR);
    }

    // getting strings lengths
    int fLEN = strlen(num_first) - 1;
    int sLEN = strlen(num_second);

    int i;
    int e = 0; // difference between two string lengths

    // here we get the difference and it's the place which i want to shif the arrays

    char *temp;
    char *zerofill = '\0';
    zerofill = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));

    if (fLEN>sLEN) // first string is bigger than second
    {
        e = fLEN-sLEN;
        for(i=0;i<e;i++)
        {
            int h = 0;
            zerofill[i] = '0';
            temp = (char*)realloc(zerofill, (i + 2) * sizeof(char));
        if (temp != NULL)
        {
            zerofill = temp; // moving temporary data to main array
        }
        else
        {
            free(zerofill);
            printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
            return 1;
        }
        }

        strcat(zerofill,  num_second);
        free(zerofill);

    }
    else if (sLEN>fLEN) // second string is bigger than first
    {
        e = sLEN-fLEN;
    }
    else // there is no difference between two strings
    {
        e = fLEN-sLEN;
    }

    puts(zerofill);

}
```

Comment: `zerofill` is allocated to hold a single char, but you later write more than a single char with `zerofill[i]`

Comment: You need to rework your loop. You have `zerofill[i] = '0';` before you've `realloc`ated the space needed to index by the given value of `i`.

Comment: fixed code maybe?? i understand codes better.

Comment: I spent so much time tying to fix it but couldn't.

Comment: fLEN>sLEN: `zerofill = malloc(fLEN+1);`..`sprintf(zerofill, "%0*d%s", e, 0, num_second);puts(zerofill);free(zerofill);`